# Google Analytics Enhanced E-Commerce is sent but not reported

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce

I've enabled enhanced ecommerce on Google Analytics, 
then in the code Im setting up a product, and action and then sending an event so the ec package gets sent. Something like:

```
ga('ec:addProduct', ecproduct);
// detail: a view of product details
ga('ec:setAction', 'detail');
//save to local storage to ensure product consistency across funnels
Cookies.set("ec_prod_"+ecproduct.id, ecproduct);
Cookies.set("ec_cart_prod", ecproduct);
ga('send', 'event', 'Online Purchase', 'Detail');
```

I have the Google Analytics Debugger extension installed and I can tell that the data is being sent:

[image: Google Analytics Debugger Extension output]

But it is not appearing in the analytics ecommerce overview report! I do get reports of the events that I'm sending, though:

[image]

Comment: How long did you wait. It takes 24 - 48 hours for data to complete processing and show up in standard reports.

Comment: Thanks. I implemented over a week ago.

Comment: I'm not certain about this as I'm not at my computer, but I don't think overview shows you product views. Try checking in the Sales Performance report for that particular event that you've sent. Also could try checking Shopping Behavior report, too. Also make sure you don't have any filters filtering out your visits.

Comment: Sales performance report is also empty. I have a yellow notification in that view on the top right that reads "This report has been filtered to include only data where there are values for "Transaction ID" dimension"